# How to add custom fields in json response directive of Alexa custom skill?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have integrated `Alexa Voice Services` into my WPF application. Idea is to provide `VUI` to application. For this I am creating a Lambda function for handling request and to send response back to application. But problem is I am not able to implement or add some of custom fields in Json response so that I can manipulate my application based on that fields.

Is there any way to add custom field to Json response or any other way to archive it?

Thanks.